# Java thread waiting to lock object it already locked

Tags: java, thread-dump

Analyzing a thread dump, I have many threads which are waiting to lock a monitor which has already locked. In the example below the monitor 0x000000044158d3d0 is fetched and locked at the same time.

Any clue about this case?

```
"ORB Run Thread" #124 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f16a81b6800
nid=0x76f3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f165eef2000]   
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000044158d3d0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.run(ORBImpl.java:1238)
    - locked <0x000000044158d3d0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaORBService$ORBRunner.run(CorbaORBService.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x000000044158d3d0> (a java.lang.Object)
```

The thread isn't waiting to lock the object. It's waiting for another thread to call [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) or [`notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--).